# how to make the list of conversation to work efficiently?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, have created a chat using reactjs. I'm using "POST" request through fetch to post new message for a particular conversation. My Objective is when i send a message, then it should clear the input but unable to clear the input after sending message. Anyone can help me in this?

"[How to post message through API successfully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59064234/how-to-post-message-through-api-successfully?noredirect=1#comment104368267_59064234)"

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to read `value` in your `Input` from the state, and then reset the state after sending the request:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSend = event => {
    const { phonNo } = this.props.phonNo;
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("phone : " + "+" + phonNo);
    this.setState({ toPhoneno: phonNo });
    console.log("phonefkjdk : " + "+" + this.state.toPhoneno);
    const data = {
      toPhoneNumber: "+" + this.state.toPhoneno,
      body: this.state.body
    };
    fetch("/api/messages", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({body: ''}); // reset input value
      });
  };

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="sendMessage"
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          id="body"
          name="body"
          value={this.state.body || ''} //read value from the state
        />
        <Button onClick={this.handleSend} className="sendBtn" icon>
          <Icon name="send" color="blue" />
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting error as "Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input" What to do?

Comment: Can't see what's wrong without seeing the code, which you removed from the question.

Comment: I've updated the link, Could you please check it once

Comment: Can you please check the above link, I've updated in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of using the controlled inputs, you can use the uncontrolled inputs also as there is no need to re-render the component on each value entered.

[Controlled vs Uncontrolled Inputs](https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/)

Following the above link, once you are done sending the message, you can easily clear the input as

`this.input.value = ''`

Controlled inputs are mostly used when you need to update the state immediately when u type. I feel you might not need it here.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple Javascript for this.
After your API response, type this where you want the input box to be cleared.

```
document.getElementById('myInput').value = '';
```

**UPDATE:**

Use ReactDOM to change the value as follows:

```
<input type="text" ref="input" />
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.input).value = '';
```

Comment: Using direct DOM manipulation inside React component is a bad idea.

Comment: It's better to do it via state manipulation than using refs in a jQuery style way.